# How to use multirom with Android M

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow, multirom-manager

I can't seem to find a kexec-hardboot patched kernel compatible with CM 13 for the Nexus 5. Is there such a thing? What should I do to getmultirom working on Nexus 5 with CM 13 as the main rom?

Answer (score 0):

Use ElementalX kernel. Works on my Nexus 5
http://elementalx.org/devices/nexus-5/

Comment: I gave that a shot; hosed Sailfish and didn't help. (Not your fault, I did it before.)